# change print style after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This:

```
<link id="printstyle" href="oldprintstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />

$('#printStyle2').click(function () {
    $("#printstyle").attr('href', _printStyle2);
    window.print();
    return false;
});
```

kind of works. I say kind of, as the actual print style is only applied after I click the button with the id 'printStyle2' a second time. What could be the reason for this behavior? Some kind of caching of the old print style?

Comment: Maybe the browser need some time to apply all the changes, try `window.setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 1000);` and see if this help.

Comment: Might be useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12272275/447356

Comment: Thanks! Your first comment did the trick. Please post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The browser needs indeed some time to apply all the changes. So:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { window.print(); }, 1000);
```

does the trick.