# JavaScript - Dynamically loaded CSS: CSS variable not visible for JS but gets evaluated from CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-variables

I load some stylesheets dynamically via JavaScript into my application. In this stylesheets I have different CSS variables that I want to read / write from my JS.

Stylesheets that are embeded directly in the head tag are handled correctly. The CSS variable gets evaluated by CSS and is visible in JS.

Stylesheets that are loaded dynamically during runtime do have some strange error. The CSS variable gets evaluated by CSS but **is not** visible by JS.

Anybody have an hint?

Plunker with minimal demo of error:

https://plnkr.co/edit/EChqjvZQJp7yz3L6nknU?p=preview

Method I use to load the CSS dynamically:

```
var fileref = document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", "not_embedded_from_start.css");

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Method I use to read the CSS variable:

```
var cS = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("html"));
var pV = cS.getPropertyValue('--foo');
```

Example CSS:

```
:root {
  --foo: green
}

#foo {
  background-color: var(--foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the stylesheet is not done loading at runtime, and therefore the CSS variable is not accessible to JS until later.

To do that, you [simply attach an `onload` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644072/dynamically-load-css-stylesheet-and-wait-for-it-to-load) to your dynamically added stylesheet, so that it calls a function, say `stylesheetLoaded()`, when it is done loading (hence accessible to JS):

```
var fileref=document.createElement("link");
fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.onload = function(){ stylesheetLoaded(); }
fileref.setAttribute("href", "not_embedded_from_start.css");
```

Note that it is strongly recommended to **attach the `onload` handler before setting the `href` attribute**.

And then you can execute whatever logic you want in that function call:

```
var stylesheetLoaded = function() {
  cS = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("html"));
  pV = cS.getPropertyValue('--baz');
  document.getElementById("baz").innerText = pV;
}
```

See proof-of-concept fork of your code: https://plnkr.co/edit/OYXk7zblryLs3F5VM51h?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day!